# Parse json string stored in database to render D3 tree layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to populate a D3 expandable tree layout using the json I get from a stored string in mysql database.

I grab the json from mysql as follows:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../connect/database.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {functionname: 'read_from_database', arguments: [user_id]},
            success: function (obj, textstatus) {
            if( !('error' in obj) ) {
               localStorage.setItem('json_string', JSON.stringify(obj.query_result.stored_json_string));
              }
            else {
               console.log(obj.error);
              }
             }
            });
```

This sets the json string to local storage. Works perfect.

I then grab this string out of local storage like this:

```
var json_string = localStorage.getItem('json_string');
```

This gives me the string I need for the D3 layout. It is in the same format as the flare.json file used on the D3 site.

The main part of D3 that renders the tree from the data is this part. I have simply added the json_string from local storage, and used the JSON.parse inside the d3.json call. This is also fired 2 seconds after fetching the data so I have confirmed the json_string is indeed loaded.

```
d3.json(json_string, function(json) {
root = JSON.parse(json);
root.x0 = h / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

function toggleAll(d) {
if (d.children) {
  d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
  toggle(d);
}
} 

// Initialize the display to show a few nodes.
root.children.forEach(toggleAll);
toggle(root.children[1]);
toggle(root.children[1].children[2]);
toggle(root.children[9]);
toggle(root.children[9].children[0]);
update(root);
});
```

But this gives the following error in the browser:

```
GET http://blahblahdotcom/path/tree/%22%7B/%22name/%22:/%22flare/%…%7D,%7B/%22name/%22:/%22Visualization/%22,/%22size/%22:16540%7D]%7D]%7D%22 414 (Request-URI Too Long)
d3.xhr @ d3.js:385
d3.text @ d3.js:395
d3.json @ d3.js:398
load_tree @ tree.html:65
(anonymous) @ tree.html:190
tree.html:67 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x0' of null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3.json` is for [async loading](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json) a `.json` file. Because you have already loaded the JSON, you do not need to use it.

You could replace your `jQuery.ajax` call with it, but assuming that you want to continue loading the data with jQuery, you can just remove the `d3.json` call.

```
var root = JSON.parse(json_string);
// ...
```

**Edit:**

You are also stringifying the `obj.query_result.stored_json_string` that is loaded from the server, but it is already a string so this is unnecessary and would require you to have to call `JSON.parse` twice in order to get the desired object.

```js
const serverValue = '{"a": "b"}';
console.log('serverValue =', serverValue, typeof serverValue);

// when you stringify a string, you get an escape string
const stringified = JSON.stringify(serverValue);
console.log('stringified =', stringified, typeof stringified);

// the first time that you parse that, you get a string
const firstParse = JSON.parse(stringified);
console.log('firstParse =', firstParse, typeof firstParse);

// the second time that you parse, you get an object
const secondParse = JSON.parse(firstParse);
console.log('secondParse =', secondParse, typeof secondParse);
```

You should just store the `stored_json_string` directly.

```
if( !('error' in obj) ) {
  localStorage.setItem('json_string', obj.query_result.stored_json_string);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried this and gives the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: I have stored the flare.json, as shown on https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083, as a string in my DB. So there shouldn't be any issues with json formatting.

Comment: Which `forEach` call is throwing the error? The `root.children.forEach` one?

Comment: On the line root.children.forEach(toggleAll);

Comment: Have you inspected the `root` object? That seems to imply that the object does not have a `children` array.

Comment: It's odd. Both alert(typeof(JSON.parse(json_string))) and alert(typeof(json_string)) give 'string' as the type.

Comment: That is because you are stringifying the JSON returned by your ajax call. The result is already a string, so when you parse it, you are getting back the original string. Just store the result without stringifying it.

Comment: It's still a string even when you don't stringify it when stored. I don't think local storage can store objects. They automatically get stringified. Parse is supposed to convert the string to an object.

Comment: What is `typeof obj.query_result.stored_json_string`?

Comment: It wa a string. I change it to an object, but localstroage converts it to string.